# Deactivate ime mode onBlur

Tags: mode, ime

I have an input field whose imeMode is set active. So when I enter this field it activates my imeMode so I can type japanese. But when I leave this textfield my ime is still active. How do i deactivate ime upon leaving the field. I can maybe put something on onblur but Don't know what to do there. I foolishly tried setting this textfield's ime mode to inactive onblur but ofcourse it will take effect only when I enter this textfield again. I was hoping that  on unfocus i can deactivate the ime allowing to input romaji on other fields without setting there ime-mode to inactive one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input onblur='this.style.imeMode="disabled"' onfocus='this.style.imeMode="active"' id='something' />
```

Comment: The prob is this will disable ime only for this particular input field.